my loop stops comparing after a certain index
I have problem with my code specifically the for loop, where i search for the smallest and largest number in my list. It stops comparing a[i] with the current smallest or largest number at some point.
I tried it with the input 23,34,68,3,566,2,1
 largest = None
    smallest = None
    a = []
    while True:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        try:
            FailureCond = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            print("that's not a number")
            continue
        a.append(num)
        continue

    for i in range(len(a)):

        if smallest is None:
            smallest = a[i]
            largest = a[i]

        if a[i] < smallest:
            smallest = a[i]

        if a[i] > largest:
            largest = a[i]


    print("current list >",a)
    print("the smallest number is >",smallest)
    print("largest number is >",largest)


the output is
current list > ['23', '34', '68', '3', '566', '2', '1']
the smallest number is > 1
largest number is > 68

i tried printing every step of the loop, but i can't seem to find the mistake

Probably because you are not comparing numbers, but strings. '68' is the "highest" string value in your array there, because strings are compared character-by-character, from left to right.

You should always tag your questions with a language ([tag:python]?).

After reviewing your code, I found the error that makes your code break in "weird" circumstances. It is the while loop where you input your numbers; if you look closely at the docs for the input function, you can see that the returned value gets transformed into a string, meaning that all of the following arithmetic operations seemed to be okay up to a certain point, however, in reality, the operations don't make sense. I fixed the part that is problematic in the following code snippet:
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        FailureCond = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("that's not a number")
        continue
    a.append(int(num)) # This line was fixed
    continue


And a reminder for future question, you should mention or tag the language you use, in this case it was easier to see that it is Python, but for clarity's sake :)

Thank you so much , I was wondering, because my loop seemed fine. I would have never came to that answers. Thanks

I tryed the following in python and it works.

largest = None
smallest = None
a = []

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)  # Convert num to an integer
    except ValueError:
        print("that's not a number")
        continue
    a.append(num)

for num in a:
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
        largest = num
    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    if num > largest:
        largest = num

print("current list >", a)
print("the smallest number is >", smallest)
print("largest number is >", largest)


The output:
current list > [23, 34, 68, 3, 566, 2, 1]
the smallest number is > 1
largest number is > 566

thanks that works, but i am still a little confused  confused, since it should work the same with using the array indexis.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
